# getClass.getFields returns fields from Scala Reflection library instead of fields from package

Tags: scala, reflection

I am using the Scala reflection library to access and execute the main() function of a jar that I have attached to my project. I can do this much successfully, but now I would like to use Reflection to access a specific field in this jar and set its value at runtime.

However, when I run the code below, `fields.map(f => print(f))` prints the fields of the Scala Reflection library, not the fields of the jar. Any idea why this is happening? I've been searching for a resolution for a week, and would greatly appreciate any help!

**Code:**

```
val rm = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror

val staticClass = rm.staticModule("com.dummy.package.name")

val im1 = rm.reflectModule(staticClass)

val x = im1.instance

val im = rm.reflect(x)

val fields = staticClass.getClass.getDeclaredFields

fields.map(f => print(f))
```

**Output:**

> public final scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.scala$reflect$internal$Symbols$Symbol$$initOwner
>   public final scala.reflect.internal.Names$Name scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.scala$reflect$internal$Symbols$Symbol$$initName
>   public final scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.$outer

Answer (score 0):

`getClass` here is the usual `Object.getClass` method, which returns the class of `staticClass` object, not the class it represents. If you are more familiar with Java reflection, the equivalent is doing `Something.class.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` instead of `Something.class.getDeclaredFields()`.

If `com.dummy.package.name` is actually a Scala `object`, then you can do

```
im1.instance.getClass
```

(`instance` returns the mirrored object). If it's the static part of a Java class (or you don't know), I think

```
rm.runtimeClass(im1.companion.asClass)
```

but I am not sure and can't test at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Using this, I am able to see the declared methods of the "main" class, which extends App. These methods include executionStart, args[], and delayedInit, from the App class.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to inspect elements of a subpackage defined within the same jar? I am able to import "com.dummy.package.Main" but not "com.dummy.package.config"